# Как в OpenGL 4 использовать только 1 цветовой канал для альфы изображения?

Tags: c#, opengl

Я записал альфа канал изображения в файл таким образом:

```
        Bitmap tex = (Bitmap)texturePreVive.Image;
        FileStream writer = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName + ".fontTex",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
        for (int y = 0; y < tex.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < tex.Width; x++)
            {
                Color color = tex.GetPixel(x, y);
                writer.WriteByte(color.A);
            }
        }
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
```

В программе с OpenGL я записал его в текстуру таким образом:

```
gl.TexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, 1028, 1028, 0, GL_R8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, File.ReadAllBytes("Orbitron.fontTex"));
```

Фрагментный шейдер выглядит так:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D tex;
void main()
{
     color = vec4(0,1,0,texture(tex,texCoord).r);
}
```

Но ничего не показывается. Как это исправить?

P.S. Использую библеотеку `SharpGL`.

Comment: Что именно вы хотите реализовать и что не получается в текущем решении?

Comment: @Kromster я хочу сделать рендер текста при помощи текстуры. но мне по сути нужен только альфа канал так как цвет текста я устанавливаю в шейдере. в текущем решении не работает что имено я не знаю.

Comment: Так, вы описали ожидаемый результат. Теперь опишите что происходит фактически? А другие текстуры работают? P.S. Размер 1028 смените на степень двойки (1024?)

Comment: Ловите две правки и два плюса, но в следующий раз постарайтесь в вопросе описывать цели, желаемое поведение и фактическое поведение (и/или перечисление ошибок).

Answer (score 1):

Изменил разрешение с 1028 на 1024
Тип с `GL_R8` на `GL_RED`
И всё заработало